# Extract vendor blobs and make a device tree

Tags: android, blob, android-source, cyanogenmod, device-tree

I'm trying since many time to get a CM (now Lineageos)13/14.1 build for my device, which is a Huawei Mediapad T1-A21W (codename: hwt1a21l) with EMUI 3.0 (Kit Kat 4.4.4) but i'm limited for the following reasons:

- There are no device tree to work with.
- No vendor blobs to work with.

Basically there are absolutely zero development or base to start with, so i have to make the device tree and extract the vendor blobs in order to archieve what i want.
Fortunately i have the kernel source downloaded from Huawei web.

**Well, about the device tree:**

after a lot of searches and setups i have created a device tree, but what i don't understand is when i compare mine [(this)](https://github.com/Mustang-ssc/android_device_huawei_hwt1a21l/tree/CM-14.1) with another one that i know it's completely functional, for example [this one](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_bacon/tree/cm-14.1) from my OnePlus One, the second one (OnePlus One) it has a huge amount of files and directories that mine doesn't have, so i don't understand where they came from. Also i don't really understand where some parameters are from, for example, the OnePlus One's BoardConfig.mk has a huge amount of targets (not sure if it's called that way, target=parameters) that mine doesn't have.

Maybe it is not the best idea compare a OnePlus with a Huawei because they are from different brands, but any way what i explained before it can be applied to a similar device to mine (Honor 4X codename: cherry) which is almost identical to my device in terms of hardware, they have the same cpu and board. (cannot link it because of lack of reputation).

**About the vendor blobs:**

I've tried to follow many guides that explain how to get the vendor blobs. While the 90% of them are based on existing vendor blobs, the other ones i found are based on a script called **extract-files.sh** which it is supposed to be located in **device_vendor_codename**, and automatically extact the vendor files based in the content of another file called **propietary-files.txt**.
The problem is that there is no extract-files.sh and propietary-files.txt files in my device path (device_huawei_hwt1a21l) and i don't know how i'm supposed to get them. The script is not a problem because i can download one and easily adapt it to my device, but the big problem is the specific vendor files to be extracted (propietary-files.txt) which i cannot control.

Comment: I'd guess you have to identify the proprietary files yourself if nobody else did this before. Any progress or hints you can give us here?

Answer (score 1):

You can find remaining files for your device from the `/system/etc` folder. It consists of various configurations required by your device. And then there's `build.prop` which can be renamed to `system.prop` and added to the device tree.